# FTP connect error 500

Tags: c#, ftp, filesize

I have code, where i control size of file, but i have (500) Internal Server Error, when i try to connect to ftp. When i try to connect to same ftp adress in web browser, it run, but from program not.
This is my code:

```
foreach (string Soubor in SeznamSouboru)
   {
     velikostdisk = new System.IO.FileInfo(Soubor).Length;
     FtpWebRequest request;                                
     request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(("ftp://nw....") + Path.GetFileName(Soubor));                                                                                                     
     request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpJmeno, FtpHeslo);
     request.UsePassive = true;
     request.UseBinary = true;
     request.KeepAlive = true;
     request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
     FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     velikostftp = response.ContentLength;
     //....other code                                
   }
```

Error is here:

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Have yo uany ideas?

Comment: @UğurAldanmaz In Path.GetFileName(Soubor) i have only filename, for example: INFO.EXE...I try to this path copy into webrowser and it run...Error is probably somewhere else...

Comment: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1903/Why+am+I+getting+a+500+Internal+Server+Error+message%3F
 btw you can edit your post instead of using commends